# Rendering linked list in React

Tags: reactjs, data-structures

Is it possible to render a linked list in React without first converting it into an array?

I have this Node class:

```
import React from 'react';
export class Node {
  next: Node | null = null;
  constructor(public value: string) {}

  renderSelf() {
    return <p>{this.value}</p>;
  }
}
```

So the idea was that I could maybe have a method on a SinglyLinkedList class that would be named displayList(). However it must return something, and the only thing it can return to display, is in fact an array.

It's not really a problem, it's more just of a feels bad, because then the reason to use a linked list in the first place dies for this particular problem.

I was wondering if anyone had an approach that could work, or if it is simply impossible.

Comment: I think you would eventually need to output an array containing the linked list `Node` and just `map` over them as you do in `React`. That outputting of array can result from an algorithm which **parses** your linked-list using `next` pointer but yes `React` needs an array in the end.